# Coilgun projectile force calculation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, forces, energy, inductance

Please excuse me if I am completely wrong because I am a 9th grader but I hopefully am able to explain briefly about my problem. I was trying to create a function to calculate the Force of an iron projectile (cylinder) when shot using a coilgun. (The projectile goes through the middle of the solenoid and the solenoid is turned off ($I = 0$) when the projectile is halfway through to not pull it back). I came across this [website](http://www.coilgun.eclipse.co.uk/coilgun_fundamentals_1.html) on how to calculate the force, which left me with the equation
$$F = \frac{1}{2}NI\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}x}.$$

Sadly, the website didn't provide a way to find out $\mathrm{d}F/\mathrm{d}x$. So I kept researching and was able to define it as
$$\pi r^2 \mu \frac{N}{L} \frac{\mathrm{d}I}{\mathrm{d}x}.$$

So I put the 2 equations together:
$$F=\pi r^2\mu \frac{N^3}{L} I \frac{\mathrm{d}I}{\mathrm{d}x}$$

Now, I am theoretically able to calculate the force but it seems kind of wrong because I only use the absolute permeability of iron without knowing about its mass. I am completely unsure if my equation is correct, so I would be really happy if anyone can help me verify it's correctness / correct it.

Comment: Have you taken into account that, when the current is turned off, you would get a magnetic field opposing your ball's velocity due to Faraday's law?

Comment: No, I don't know that. But won't the magnetisation of the projectile go away when the coil is turned off, not pulling it back?

Comment: The problem is quite more complex than what it may seem at first. Yes, the magnetisation could go away if your ball were a lineal material, BUT the field doesn't just disappear instantly because there is no physical way to turn off something (or do anything at all) instantly. You would get an opposing magnetic field for a few fractions of second which would oppose your ball's movement (look up Faraday-Lenz's law)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll proceed to do so, but what are your thoughts on my current calculations? And could I theoretically turn of the coil just in time that the magnetic field of my projectile goes away when it is in the middle of it? (Turn off the coil eralier)

Comment: regardless of when you turn it off, you'll always get the push back, so coils are no great cannon, unless you manage to build a coil long enough that you have time to diminish the current slowly

Comment: It'll be using multiple coils, so at least 5. I want to make a presentation about the coilgun and build one myself. I'll also show the coilgun/railgun built by the US army. I know that there will always be a push back, but I have seen some examples of coil guns and I think that I could still achieve the speed I want. (I can't make it too effective because of legalitiy and sutff, if you know what I mean), but thnak you for the reminder. But is the calculation correct, regardless of the unwanted force?